# How to delete multiple nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

How to delete multiple nodes, (NOT ALL) in neo4j?

I have this query
`MATCH (n)

where n.name IS NULL

delete n`

It returns more than one node, I want to delete all those nodes(All nodes, which are mistakenly created thats why become null).

The error, I am facing is

`javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit transaction Transaction(11, owner:"qtp16626756-84")[STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION,Resources=1], transaction rolled back ---> javax.transaction.xa.XAException`

**CASE 2:** What to do in case of NOT NULL (property) but no any relationship is associated within a node or two; means a node which is kind of orhpan, not connected with other node.

I tried to use LIMIT/SKIP but not working.Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to also delete any relationships connected to those nodes, like so:

```
match (n)
where n.name IS NULL
optional match (n)-[r]-()
delete n, r
```

Update for your second case (this deletes only orphans):

```
match (n)
where NOT (n)--()
  and n.name IS NULL
delete n
```

Comment: `All nodes, which are mistakenly created thats why became null` means only nodes has been created, I cant see relationship associated with those, either outgoing or incoming.

Comment: Maybe you need a different query to find the appropriate nodes. You might try `MATCH (n) WHERE n.name is NULL RETURN n` to check that they're the right ones.

Comment: Did you try my query? I have a feeling that `n.name IS NULL` is not what you want to query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wes. I think, as I m learning to neo4j by my own, so may b lacking to cover important things or may be misleading. Now, need to concentrate and stay tuned with masters like u.

Comment: # UPDATE 2021
I'm also new to Neo4j, but as I saw in the docs, it says if you want to delete a node/relationship property then you can use `REMOVE` or `type.prop = null` so Neo4j removes the property entirely from the node/rel, maybe the above query is not matching what you want since Neo4j has already removed that property since it doesn't store null valued properties,
check it [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/updating/#_delete_properties) on docs